# SharePoint 2010 Mobile Customization

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, mobile

I am aware that OOTB SharePoint 2010 Mobile features does not handle Workflows and InfoPath forms .

We are looking at Viewing existing SharePoint sites (it has workflows , complex InfoPath forms , client object model code) , I know these cannot be done OOTB. And I am not looking at viewing the desktop view in mobile. (Which can be achieved by disabled mobile redirection in CA)

1. Is there any way this can be achieved without having rewrite for mobile. Some 3rd party tool which could translate /render mobile view?
2. If not , Would 3rd party tool be a better option that writing /creating mobile based applications for the same?

Answer (score 2):

Whilst it won't change how infopath forms render etc there is the excellent "Responsive SharePoint". You can find out more below.

[Responsive SharePoint](http://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/)

I've also intgrated Twitter bootstrap into my own app (2013) and instead of using infopath i've created my own (modal) forms etc with workflows.

HTH.

S

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But does this support SharePoint 2010 or can it be used. I jusr downloaded the WSP docs for the same and it is mentioned it is for SharePoint 2013. any idea?

Comment: Yes this supports 2010.  http://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/100318

Comment: Thanks,I am going through the same . one more question , so we would be disabling mobile redirection right?. So basically we would be rendering the desktop view but since we have responsive design it adapts to devices right? So will workflows and Infopath forms works fine? or do i need to change that as well , coz the all the sites are already in prod .

Comment: Yes that is correct. Cant see an issue with worlkflows but maybe one with Infopath but as I said i build my own forms which are responsive. I do not use infopath.